# My laptop works only when the second monitor is plugged in

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, 22.04, multiple-monitors

I have recently installed Kubuntu 22.04 (kernel version 5.19.0-40 generic) in Dual Boot with Windows on my HP envy-13.

My problem is that Kubuntu works only when my second monitor is plugged into laptop through a USB-C to VGA adapter. When the second monitor is not plugged in kubuntu won't boot and when I unplug it during a working session my laptop totally freezes and I have to turn it off manually.

On the other hand Windows boots perfectly on my laptop.

Do you have any idea of the source of this?

Thanks in advance,

PS: here are some outputs to my prompts

```
$ lsb_release -a

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company UHD Graphics 620
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 138
        Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
        Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
        Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
...
```

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:138 memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```